# How to achive Rser in a voltage in ngspice like in LTspice

Tags: voltage, resistance, ngspice

I'd like to add Rser into my V1 like in the image below, but I couldn't find how to do it. I checked the internet, looked at ngspice's manual. I tried adding resistance next to V1 but PP value of out1 reading is 10 although it should be ~9.98 which was measured in LTspice

[image]

I appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure your discrepancy is caused by the lack of `Rser`?  Have you compared LTspice's reading using `Rser` versus LTspice's reading using an explicit resistor?  Also, why are you assuming ~9.98V is correct?

Comment: `Rser` is specific to LTspice (though other simulators may implement parasitics, as well). Ngspice doesn't have parasitics (you said you looked in the manual). "*I tried adding resistance next to V1*" -- was it series or parallel?

Comment: Not a good idea to combine because you lose sight of a component and mistakes follow.